# Exponential problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

$\$10,000$ increases every day by $1\%$. How long until it doubles? I tried doing it by multiplying by $1\%$ for each day and got $10$ days but I don't think that is right. I know there must be an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Find a formula that tells you how much money you have after $n$ days. For example:

After $0$ days, you have $a_0=10,000$.

After $1$ day, you have $a_1=10,000 + 0.01\cdot 10,000 = 10,000 \cdot 1.01$

After $2$ days, you have $a_2 = a_1 + 0.01\cdot a_1 = 1.01a_1 = 10,000\cdot 1.01\cdot 1.01=10.000\cdot 1.01^2$...

Can you see a pattern?

Answer (score 1):

How about this: you want to find the value of $t$ so that : $$ (1+ \frac {1}{100})^t=2$$

This follows from the fact that every day your money increases by $1$% .Day $1$ you have $10,000$. Day $2$ , you have $10,000+ \frac{1}{100}\times 10,000=10,000(1+ \frac {1}{100}) $ (equality follows by factoring $10,000$ from both terms ). Every day, the amount of money is multiplied by this same amount $(1+ \frac {1}{100})$

Then you can isolate  (and solve for ) $t$ by taking $ln$ on both sides:

I'm not sure how your calculator works, but maybe you can use the identity $$(1+\frac{1}{100})^t=e^{t.ln(1.01)} $$ as a function of $t$, after finding the numerical value for $ln(1.01)$, plug in values of $t$. Does this work?

Comment: I feel like the OP would need help arriving at this equation, so it's not very helpful to him just posting it (otherwise if he knew how to I'm guessing he wouldn't have asked for help).

Comment: @DanZimm: Maybe you're right. Let's see if the OP has something to say; if not, I will try to rewrite. I also want to avoid writing something too similar to the other answer.

Comment: ya to be honest im not sure how you got to that equation. or how I would run it through my graphing calculator but i know that would be much easier then keep on multiplying it by 1% if I can figure it out.

Comment: @Jack: let me rewrite to try to make it more clear.

Comment: @Jack In order to get to that equation, take a look at my anser and try to find a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Not marked as homework, so...

For day $1$, multiply $10\ 000$ by $1.01$ ($101\%$ of $10\ 000$). Continue for each day like this:

$\text{day }0:\ \ 10\ 000\\
\text{day }1:\ \ 10\ 000\times1.01\\
\text{day }2:\ \ 10\ 000\times1.01\times1.01\\
\text{day }3:\ \ 10\ 000\times1.01\times1.01\times1.01\\
\text{day }4:\ \ 10\ 000\times1.01\times1.01\times1.01\times1.01\\
\ \ \ \vdots\\
$

You *could* continue like this on a calculator till you reached $20\ 000$. Alternatively ...

For day $n$, write $10\ 000\times1.01^n$.

$1.01^n\times10\ 000=20\ 000\\
1.01^n=\dfrac{20\ 000}{10\ 000}\\
1.01^n=2$

Since $a^n=b$ can be rewritten $n=\dfrac{\ln(b)}{\ln(a)},$

$
n=\dfrac{\ln(2)}{\ln(1.01)}\text{ days}
$

For further information, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest).